# android: How to share a POJO between Activities

Tags: android, reference, android-activity, share, pojo

I am porting a program to Android. I have all my business logic on POJOs, so I need to use Activities as a mere front-end.

The problem is that I don't know how to share POJO between Activities; I've tried with this, but  it doesn't work:

```
class Activity1 extends Activity{
Logic logic=new Logic();

public Logic getLogic(){
return logic
}
}

class Activity2 extends Activity{
Logic logic;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    main = (Activity1) findViewById((R.id.Activity1);
    logic= main.getLogic(); 
}
}
```

Please note that POJO is not for sharing data, it actually contains business logic.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965109/passing-data-between-activities-in-android

Comment: not really duplicate, its not about sharing data, its about accessing data/logic across multiple activities...

Comment: I disagree. The answer above does not work for POJO, only for data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
main = (Activity1) findViewById((R.id.Activity1);
```

`findViewById` works only for views! Its not meant to be used for activities as an activity is more like a "screen" and not a view itself.

If it is possible for your business logic to be a singleton, than I would recommend to make it so. It should be the easiest way.

Comment: Please read the last two sentences. If you can make them a singleton, use it. Otherwise I suggest to extend the Application class and keep a reference to your POJOs there, so you can access them from everywhere...

Answer (score 6):

Your POJOs need to implement the Parcelable interface. Then you can put them inside Intents using putExtra and retrieve them in the next activity using getParcelableExtra. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: They don't need to implement Parceable at all... you could just use putExtra and getExtra i did that a alot of times without any problems.

Comment: That would work for basic Java data types like int, long, double etc. For your own data types you would have to implement Parcelable or Serializable.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry you're right i just recognized that all my parsed Objects are Serializables :-). I did'nt see till now that this was a requirement. Thanks for illuminating +1 *gg*

Comment: Was confused for an instant myself. Had to go through the documentation just to check. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you start another activity from one activity by issuing an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) you can pass POJOs by using the method `putExtra()`. In the new activity where you receive the Intent you can then get the POJO back by using `getXXXExtra()` where XXX ist the POJOs Type.

You should also have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html for a better understanding what Intents are and how they work together with Activities.

edit: as stated in the other answers here you'll have to implement either Parceable or Serializable Interface.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are mixing two different things: `findViewById` will get you a `View`, not an `Activity` like what you tried to do.

If your logic doesn't have to keep the state between activities, you can simply create a new object in both activities

```
Logic logic=new Logic();
```

If you want to keep the state, assuming it's a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object), you can send the data via the intent when you are "calling" the second activity

```
intent.putExtra("MyInt", 123);
intent.putExtra("MyString", "hello!");
//...
```

and then in the second activity

```
intent.getIntExtra("MyInt"); // 123
intent.getStringExtra("MyString"); //"hello!"
```

Another option is to implemente [parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) . You have a sample in that link.

Comment: I need to communicate both ways between activities and for a lot of variables this would become cumbersome... Binder is a better option.