# Save data into an email:

Tags: android, email, android-activity, save

Save data from edit texts, text views, spinner selections, and checkboxes from multiple activities into an email:

I am already using:

```
Intent EmailSend = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    EmailSend.setType("plain/text");
    EmailSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
      "Pretext"+edittext.getText().toString());
```

the put string is not working for items not listed in the .java
When I use the last line in that i get error saying -edittext cannot resolved-

and how to get data from checkbox & spinner

I will have 80 or so items to compile to this email over 8 activities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a snippet to automate it a little:

```
ViewGroup     root = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
StringBuilder str  = new StringBuilder();

public void extractText(ViewGroup root, StringBuilder str){
    int count = root.getChildCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View v = root.getChildAt(i);

        if(v instanceof Spinner) {
            str.append(i).append(" Spinner: ").append(((Spinner) v).getSelectedItem());
        } else if(v instanceof TextView) {
            str.append(i).append(" TextView: ").append(((TextView) v).getText());
        } else if(v instanceof CheckBox) {
            str.append(i).append(" Checkbox: ").append(((CheckBox) v).isChecked());
        }else if(v instanceof ViewGroup){
            extractText((ViewGroup)v, str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @dziobas I put this under  EXTRA_TEXT, ?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-email-from-my-android-application) example how to send email.

Comment: I have the intent code just fine . . . . I am not understanding your answer post please explain

Comment: Wow it seems that peoples answers are sometimes way too complicated for the real problem . . .

All i had to do was add this to the class:

    private EditText edittext;

and add this to the OnCreate:

    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

now it works like a charm

Comment: @dziobas If you dont mind I would still like to understand your first post better . . . where is that used and how does it work

Comment: I  couldn've believe that you hadn't got instance of edittext :). I thought that the problem is with big quantity of items, therefore I wrote method to automate extracting data from spinners, textviews and checkboxes from root view of activity to string. I hope that will help you.

Comment: @dziobas yes thank you if I may ask for additional advice ... I have nothing written for this so assume the stupidity i had before  :( but I need to get spinner, edittext and checkbox info from one activity and place it into the same email on the main activity . . . starting from scratch ... how would i do that?

Comment: That should help: [Passing data between activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965109/passing-data-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: @dziobas what do i put for the key and value??? getting error saying key and value cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: I don't know what key and what value.