# Application crashes on call to a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

this might not be a new question to you - I have my main activity and I would like to call a method in another activity. Now if I do this I get my application not responding and closed.

I hear there is some special way to call methods in other activity classes?

Comment: Can you please show your code or the error that you are getting.

Comment: Post the code that you are trying to use currently.

Comment: Too less information to say anything. Please elaborate. Why do u need to call a method from another activity. If its needed in 2 activities then better be global.

Answer (score 3):

This is generally a bad idea, the reason why is because you have no control of the life-cycle of an activity that is not the active Activity. You could call a method and find that the activity you are calling has been destroyed to reclaim resources.

A better option would be to create a Utility class that can provide functions to multiple activities, or place things that must remain throughout the life-cycle of your application into the application class, or shared preferences.

If all your trying to do is pass information to a new activity or get information from another one, you may want to package that information into the intent, or again place it in shared preferences.

Comment: Yes I want to pass some information that was generated in the first activity and display it in the other activities as well. Can you please explain more about this utility class and how to use that?

Comment: If your only looking to pass information you should put the data as an Extra to your Intent that calls the upcoming class.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965109/passing-data-between-activities-in-android

Comment: this data needs to be displayed on the second Activity's screen, so basically I need to send the info to another class and then somehow use the second activity to pull that info from this "utility class" and display it on screen?

Comment: No, you should pass it as an extra in the intent as per my last comment.

Comment: I used class variables to hold information in my app that I couldn't find a good way to carry across a few activies. They work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just create another class and place that method in that class.Then access from both activity.

Comment: I've created another class for setting and getting of information from that class. I've found out that writing to this class doesn't make the activity crash, but getting info back from this class is whats crashing my activity.

Comment: If it helps, I'm trying to change the text in a TextView with info from a utility class I've created:
public class Shifts extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
 
 Utility UT2 = new Utility();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.shifts);
 
 TextView setDate = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.shifts);
 setDate.setText(UT2.date);

}

 
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}