# Determining which value of IntentExtra has been sent

Tags: android

I want to determine which value has been sent by different buttons that I have in my code. I have tried the code below.
Thanks in advance!

```
if (intent.getExtras().getString("") == button1value){
}
```

Comment: your solution should be [this..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965109/passing-data-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: you've tried this... and the problem was...?

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare two strings with `==`.

```
if (intent.getExtras().getString("").equals(button1value)) {
}
```