# How start a new Activity and send parameter?

Tags: android, android-activity

I wanna start a new activity and sent a parametter to her. And according to what has been sent activity will behave in a way or another. (Sorry my bad english) The options depends of a button. If "option1" or "option2" is pressed, the SettingsActivity will come the same, except in a little details, so I have send a parameter to separate the two ways inside "SettingsActivity".

I have the next:

```
option1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });
option2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965109/passing-data-between-activities-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the  `.putExtra("Name", name);` and in the settingsActivity use this: `getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name");`

`.putExtra("Name", name);` - The "Name" is kind of like a temporary id,
and the second value is your string.

To get it using the `getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name");`, use something like

`String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name");` in the SettingsActivty

Comment: Thanks! I have to use .getInt() instead, but all works fine :)

Comment: well in my app I used a String so sorry, ya .getInt() work just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

To call a new activity you can do this thing by the following code. where a intent can call a newactivity. here xyz is the current activity and xyz1 class is the target activity.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(xyz.this, zyz1.class);
 i.putExtra("post", 2);
 startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using this method and works fine :) your link not works :S