# How to call a function present in one class from another class?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to call a function present in one class from another class by creating its object. Somehow it's not working. The new activity doesn't load.

My java code:

```
public class MessagesActivity extends TabActivity {

    public WorkEntryScreenActivity workEntryObject = new WorkEntryScreenActivity() ;

    public void AddWorkEntryClick(View v) {
        workEntryObject.newWorkEntry();
    }
}
```

The other class:

```
public class WorkEntryScreenActivity extends Activity {

public void newWorkEntry() {
    try {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, WorkEntryActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("CurDate", mDateDisplay.getText());
        i.putExtra("DD", String.valueOf(mDay));
        i.putExtra("MM", String.valueOf(mMonth));
        i.putExtra("YYYY", String.valueOf(mYear));
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception" + e.getStackTrace());
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception" + e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997996/why-arent-getters-preferred-when-accessing-variables-between-activities/10998128#10998128  Possibly related, w.r.t. answers..

Comment: The fact you're creating an instance of Activity (as if it were usual Java) tells you are missing Android basics. Read the basics guide first (biovamp points the link).

Comment: @Arhimed I'm new to android and I've been reading about it as much as got a chance to since then. Though I still couldn't figure out a way to call a function present in another class. I've come across a few examples where people do create an instance of an activity, like I noticed in switching tabs most people use `MyTabActivity myTab = (MyTabActivity) getParent();` I tried even this:
`public void AddWorkEntryClick(View v) {
  WorkEntryScreenActivity object = (WorkEntryScreenActivity) getParent();
  object.newWorkEntry();
 }` didn't work! Any suggestions?

Comment: @Harsh: in most cases (I'm not familiar with TabActivity) activities to do not communicate directly (as it would be in a standard Java), but they can communicate via `Activity.startActivityForResult()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create your workEntryObject first (it's not C++). Like this

```
public WorkEntryScreenActivity workEntryObject=new WorkEntryScreenActivity();
```

Also, I highly recommed you to read Android Basics
http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Comment: Wow! I've lost it. Anyway thanks. 

Now it doesn't give me any errors but it doesn't load the new activity

Comment: To create new Activity use `startActivity()` method of your current Activity. You can read about this here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Answer (score 0):

@biovamp is correct. It looks like you have a null reference that you're trying to call a method on. In order to call a non-static method, you need a instance of that object.

From the naming of your method, it looks like you might be trying to re-use some of your UI in another part of your application. In Android, the way to accomplish that is through [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) and [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html). If you're not familiar with those or how to use them, I would highly suggest researching them.