# passing data between activities with bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to pass data from one activity that getting a bluetooth (4) data, to another activity.

which is better: do i need to send it by `Intent` , or call the bluetooth once more ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051839/how-to-pass-information-between-activities

Comment: send it by intent. Why to waste resources?