# Child Activity Not receiving data?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I am learning android, so I was practising with a program in which I start a new activity with a button and then what ever text was input by the user in the edittext of the previous activity has to displayed in textview of the new started activity but when I pass the user input to the new activity, it doesn't display anything. What can be the problem here is the code:
Lets say this parent activity:

```
        case R.id.Sfr:
        Intent data= new Intent(SendData.this, RecieveData.class);
        Bundle check = new Bundle();

        check.putString("UmerData", cheese);
        medt.setText(cheese);
        data.putExtras(check);
        startActivityForResult(data, 5); // It is used to return data from child activity
        break;
```

The child activity which should show the user input passed to it is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recievedata);
    Initialize(); 
    Bundle got = getIntent().getExtras();

    rt1.setText(got.getString("UmerData"));

}
```

Why is this child activity not showing userinput which has been passed to it?

Comment: Why you're using `startActivityForResult` Do you think this is the one  which is starting new Activity.

Comment: it is for another button.That is when the child activity starts, the user selects some radiobutton and according to that the data is passed back to the parent child when ReturnData button is pressed in child activity.

Comment: Where is the `RecieveData.java` Is it in the same class `SendData.java`?

Comment: no. RecieveData is the child class and SendData is parent class

Comment: In your question's `onCreate()` code located in which class?

Comment: oncreate is in child class and switch case thing is in parent class.

Comment: Okay, now, these are in seperate class or both are in same class?

Comment: I told that they are in separate class.

Comment: Then, you've to use `startAcitivy` instead of `startActivityForResult`

Comment: but then I would have to create a new intent and start new activity for passing data to parent class. This will be cumbersome. I am looking for a more intutive way.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people)

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
case R.id.Sfr:
    Intent data= new Intent(SendData.this, RecieveData.class);
    Bundle check = new Bundle();
    check.putString("UmerData", cheese);
    medt.setText(cheese);
    data.putExtras(check);
    startActivity(data);
    break;
```

The child activity which should show the user input passed to it is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recievedata);
    InitializeFuck();
    Bundle got = getIntent().getExtras();
    rt1.setText(got.getString("UmerData"));
}
```

Have a look at these existing answers -

1. [Passing Data between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2965248/940096)
2. [How to pass the Data between Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091482/940096)

Answer (score 1):

write in first activity:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putStringExtra("keyForData", Value);
startActivity(intent);
```

write code in second Activity:-

```
Intent intent = Activity2.this.getIntent();
String data  =intent.getStringExtra("KeyForData");
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use `Intent` along with `putExtra()` for **sending data** to the `Another Activity`.

**Eg:**

```
   Intent i = new Intent(Your_Class.this, Desired_Class.class);

   i.putExtra("NameKey","name");

   startActivity(i);
```

**2.** Now use `getIntent()` on the **receiving Activity** to get the `Starting Intent` and then use
       `getExtras()` and `getString()` to **get the String value associated with the key**. We have `getInt()` **etc too..**

**Eg:**

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();

   String name = intent.getExtras().getString("NameKey");
```