# Pass information between android activites

Tags: android, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing data between activities in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965109/passing-data-between-activities-in-android)

I'm trying to pass a string from my main activity to another activity I have created.
How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to save your information into a bundle as an extras. Please see the code below

This would be for your First activity

```
String customerName = "Bob";
Bundle b = new Bundle();
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),work.class);

b.putString("Name", customerName);  
myIntent.putExtras(b);
v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
```

Then to access the information in the other(Second) activity please see the code below

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String name = b.getString("customerName");
```

Comment: Is *this* an answer to your post?

Answer (score 0):

try this

> FirstActivity

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Your_KEY", "YOUR_STRING_VALUE");

Intent newIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
```

> SecondActivity

```
Bundle bundle = SecondActivity.this.getIntent().getExtras();
String s = bundle.getString("Your_KEY");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the secondActivity

> public static String myName;
>
> myName = "Miguel";

When you want to get it in the mainActivity:

```
 String s1;

 s1= secondActivity.myName;
```