# How do I save some textviews and load them from another class?

Tags: java, android, loading, save

In my app, i have you put in some information through some edit text. Then you hit this button and it starts another activity that does some calculations and then displays results through text views. Well i want to be able to save all of those text views, and then open them up later. On the home screen i have a load button. When you click it, I want to be able to see the stuff I've saved and be able to open it by clicking on it. I'm new to android, so I'm having a hard time figuring this out. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences...Check out..

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html

http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.in/2013/01/sharedpreference-in-android.html

this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I see two questions in your question.  The first is how to pass data from one Android activity to another.

The best way to do that is by using the `putExtra` method of the Intent class and then the `getExtras` method to extract the data in the receiving activity.  Please see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965109/passing-data-between-activities-in-android) quest and answers for more details.

For your second question, how to save data that can be recalled at a later by the main activity, you can use the `SharedPreferences` APIs.  See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) web page for more information on that.  Basically the shared preferences APIs allow you to save key-value pairs of information which in your case can be field names (keys) and their associated values.  For this you would want private preferences and pick a unique name for this preference file.