# Android - onclick, change TextView content , background colour and set visibility gone

Tags: android, android-intent, background, textview

Hi I am very new to Android development. Here is my problem:

In have two activities as shown below.

- **Activity1.class XML**--> has two buttons

  **Button1**  (Id:@+id/btn1 , onclick:doTHIS) and
  **Button2**  (Id:@+id/btn2 , onclick:doTHAT)
- **Activity2.class XML**--> has a TextView with this parameters

  **Textview**  (Id:@+id/texter  ,  Text:@+string/text1  ,  background:#ffffff)

onClick of Button1, I want to go to Activity2 and change

- the background of a TextView to #000000
- the Text to @+sting/text2

onClick of Button2, I want go to Activity2 and

- set the TextView to visible:gone (not visible)

I tried to do this with no results.

```
public void doTHIS(View view){
    TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texter);
    tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.text2));
    tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to solve my problem?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Is the Activity2 not launching?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It crashes on Activity2. Actually I know how to load the activity2. but I am not able to change the parameters of my textview (Textstring,Background and visibility).

Comment: Add the code for Activity2.

Comment: Thats the xml    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/texter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/text1"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
    </LinearLayout>

Comment: thats the code of activity 2     import android.app.Activity;import android.os.Bundle;public class Lettore extends Activity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
 }
};

Comment: I tried to write this : public void doTHIS(View view) {
  final TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.texter);
  tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);    but I get an error FATAL EXEPTION:main   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity     at android.view.View$1.onClick etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change controls on another layout until it's loaded. In other words, when you're in Activity1, you can't change TextView that's in layout for Activity2.

I'm sure there are a couple of ways to achieve what you want though. One of them would be to pass a flag in an Intent to Activity2, indicating which button has been pressed, and act accordingly.

1. In Activity1, let's pass integer 1 if Button1 was pressed, and 2 if Button2 was pressed, so change your click listeners as follows:

   ```
   public void doTHIS(View view) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
       intent.putExtra("button", 1);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   public void doTHAT(View view) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
       intent.putExtra("button", 2);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
   ```
2. In Activity2, in onCreate(), check which button called this activity, and do your changes (note: we're doing this AFTER setContentView()):

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

       //now, let's check which button got us here
       int button = getIntent().getIntExtra("button", 1);

       TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texter);

       switch (button) {
           case 1:
               tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.text2));
               tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
               //whatever else you want to do
               break;
           case 2:
               tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               break;    
       }

       //rest of your code
   }
   ```

Read more on passing data between activities [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965109/passing-data-between-activities-in-android).