# issue in passing the username to another activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to pass the data from Sign up activity to Profile activity! 
I wanna pass the username and the birthday. I've tried to use the intent but for some reason that didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between activities in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965109/passing-data-between-activities-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

in your signup activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("username",username);
intent.putExtra("birthday",birthdate);
startActivity(intent):
```

in your Profile Activity onCreate method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
String birthday = intent.getStringExtra("birthday");
```

I would kindly suggest you to make a search next time, before you post :)
The question you asked is asked many times:)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't make any difference I don't know why :(

Comment: After getting those variables, you should setText()  to your TextViews in Profile Activity

Comment: If It works, you can now modify your code to make it nicer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

This is a very simple question just pass the data to another activity with intent or bundle and get the data from another activity and set in the layouts as you want