# Passing dynamically generated CheckBox values to another Activity only returns a Null?

Tags: android, android-activity, checkbox, gettext

If I programmatically create checkboxes as follows:

```
private Fruits fruits = new Fruits();

final String color = ...  //user input from another control
final List<String> listFruits = fruits.getFruits(color);
final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

...

for (int i = 0; i < listFruits.size(); i++)
{
   final CheckBox chkFruits = new CheckBox(Main_Activity.this);
   chkFruits.setText(listFoods.get[i]);

   ll.addView(chkFruits);

   //insert code here on how to pass data of checked checkboxes to my next Activity_2
}
```

And my Fruits class is as follows:

```
public class Fruits {
   List<string> getFruits(String color) {
      List<String fruits = new ArrayList<String>();

      if (color.equals="red"){
         fruits.add("Apple");
         fruits.add("Strawberry");
      }
      else if (color.equals="yellow"){
         fruits.add("Banana");
         fruits.add("Pineapple");
      }

      return fruits;
   }
}
```

How do I check for which generated checkboxes have been checked by the user AND THEN **pass** it's information (i.e. `setText(listFoods.get[0]` will give "Apple" if `color="red"`) to my next Activity_2?

I tried using Intent:

```
final String[] passThis = new String[1];
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

...

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
...
Intent intent = new Intent (getBaseContext(), Activity_2.class);
intent.putExtra("checkedFruits", passThis[0]);
startActvity(intent);
```

But it returns a **NULL**.  How do I get the text/value of my generated checkboxes into my next Activity_2?

EDIT:  How do I push whatever checked CheckBoxes into my `passThis[]` array so that I can pass them onto my next Activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between activities in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965109/passing-data-between-activities-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of texts of checkboxes checked and need to add clickListener on each checkbox. Try something like this:

```
   List checked<String> = new ArrayList()// stores checked checkboxes text


   for (int i = 0; i < listFruits.size(); i++)
   {
 final CheckBox chkFruits = new CheckBox(Main_Activity.this);
  chkFruits.setText(listFoods.get(i));
  chkFruits.setTag(i); // to identify checkboxes
  //add click listener to your checkboxes
  chkFruits.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CheckBox checkbox=(CheckBox)v;
            if(checkbox.isChecked())
            {
                int pos=(int)checkbox.getTag();
                checkbox.setChecked(false);
                checked.remove(pos);

            }else
            {
                checkbox.setChecked(true);
                checked.add(checkbox.getText());
            }

        }
    });      
  ll.addView(chkFruits);

}
```

you can pass `checked` list to next Activity.